# How to get result from 3 tables with relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables.

Blogs_table

-> id

-> product_id

Products_table

-> id

->name

-> company_id

Company_table

->id

->name

Now I need to show all the blogs alongwith product name and company name.
How to do this with relationship in laravel please help?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are asking for all the blogs each with his product name and product's company name ,, assuming each company has many products and each product has many blogs you are going to do somthing like this

#### Eloquent

```
//fetch all blogs with respective product and company
$blogs = Blog::with('transactions' , 'product' , 'product.company')->get();
//fetch all blogs with respective product and company specifically name colums
$blogs = Blog::with('transactions' , 'product:name' , 'product.company:name')->get();
```

#### Blog Model

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

#### Product Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(blog::class);
    }
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(company::class);
    }
}
```

#### Compay Model

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

for more read about   [eloquent relationships : eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)